# Access 2010 Frontend Passing Queries to an SQL Server 2014 Backend

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I recently have transferred an Access Backend to an SQL Server and now I know how to pass queries through to the SQL Server to make him do the calculation. But this only works if the queries that only contain Tables i e.g.:

Q_Test:

```
SELECT * FROM T_Test
```

but what if i want to pass a query through to the Server that contains another query (and this query contains some other queries too) e.g.:

Q_Test3:

```
SELECT * FROM Q_Test2
INNER JOIN ..
```

Q_Test2:

```
Select * From Q_Test..
```

Then i think its clunky and gets complicated for me to translate the code into an "only-table" SQL Code. Is there a possibility to pass through queries with included sub queries to the SQL Server in a clever way? I have saved queries in my Access Frontend and Some i open via VBA-Code and some written in Recordsources of Forms and need to change them in order to make it work. With queries that only contain tables the VBA code does work.

Im very grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you are trying to get SQL Server to use Access constructs of which the SQL Server could not possibly even know about. It knows nothing about Access queries nor any other objects that's contained in Access file.

It only knows about its own objects -- in other words, what you can see in a SQL Server Management Studio's object explorer is what you can "see" inside a pass-through query because that's the environment you are working with.

You should consider that a pass-through query allow you to use SQL Server constructs that would be foreign to Access such as stored procedures or table-valued functions, or some T-SQL syntax not supported in Access SQL dialect.

With that in mind, you should be writing stored procedures in SSMS, testing it, and when it's right, call it from your Access pass-through query. If you need updatability (e.g. ability to bind the result to a form and editing the data), consider using a view instead. Be aware there are some restrictions on what updates are legal on a view.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I will try to read myself into stored procedures. Seems to be the right thing. However, is there a possibility to maybe save queries on the sql server so he knows the tables behind? Or to save the queries into files he can read or something?

Comment: Why not just [link your SQL Server tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-SQL-Server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) into Access app and run local queries on them? What is so needed about pass-thru queries? Unless you are using SQL Server dialect that cannot be translated to Access dialect or need operations not required of Access app, pass-thru queries may not be needed.

Comment: Because it is very slow to run the queries local. You can correct me, but i thought that was the reason to run an sql server, So it can do the calculation and only give me the result. My program is running pretty slow right now so thats why im trying out the sql server.. to make it run faster.

I also tried to open a query via vba that i passed through access. i can open it in access and it opens way faster, but if i try to open this query with vba it says it doesnt know the object "myquery"

Comment: @FabWe As Gustav alluded to, you could create a table just to store data from Access, which can be then used in server stored procedure, so that you can easily push data and then just let SQL Server process it in entirety. However, this still can be slow because when you insert several rows, Access must execute insertions one by one, it's the only reliable way to know the insertion will succeed. If that is going to be a problem, you might benefit from this old [article](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2014/01/14/working-with-xml-data-efficiently-part-one/) on how to push large amt of data.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand, that a pass-through query does just that. SQL Server has no idea what your Access application is about.

Access and the ODBC driver know this, so if you include a local query, table, or function, all handling will take place in Access.

A pass-through query can only handle server objects. *Hint*: These could, however, include a temporary table filled by your Access application.